# the insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans

```
CREATE TABLE Alumno(
    Id_Alumno char(9),
    primary key (Id_Alumno),

    Nom_Al varchar(50),
    Ape_Al varchar(50),
    Fec_Nac date,
    Grad_Esc varchar(30),
    Correo_Inst varchar(80)
);

CREATE TABLE Cuestionario(
    
    Id_Cuestionario INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
    Cod_Cuestionario as ('CUES' +RIGHT ('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Id_Cuestionario),(4))),

    Id_Alumno char(9),
    FOREIGN KEY (Id_Alumno) REFERENCES Alumno (Id_Alumno),

    Area_orientada varchar(200)
);
```

Luego en el java tengo una función que guarda la respuesta de un cuestionario:

```
void Registrar() {
    
    String resul = res1.getText();
    String idAlumno = txt_codAl_res.getText();     
    String insertar = "INSERT INTO Cuestionario (Id_Alumno, Area_orientada) VALUES (?,?)";

    try {
        ps = cin.prepareCall(insertar);

        ps.setString(1, idAlumno);
        ps.setString(2, resul);

        int registro = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (registro > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El estudiante a sido registrado con éxito.", "Bien",
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El estudiante NO a sido registrado con éxito.", "Bien",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

El error que me bota eso es este: `the insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint "FK_Cuestiona_Id_Al_2A164134". The conflict ocurred in database "TestVocacional", table "dbo.Alumno", column "Id_Alumno"`.

Comment: Saludos. Por el momento solo se me ocurre sugerirte que verifiques que el valor a insertar en tabla `Cuestionario` en la columna `Id_Alumno` sea uno existente en tabla `Alumno` en su campo `Id_Alumno`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Como dijo RobertoLeOr, para esta consulta, la tabla tiene que tener un alumno con id = 1.